# Possible reasons for file access hanging without errors

Tags: c#, file-io

With my C# application I'm quite heavily accessing different files (copying them via input and outputstreams, calculating hashes of the files contents,...).

Now time and again I've noticed that the access of the files suddenly hangs up taking the thread the file access is running in with it without any exceptions thrown.

At first I thought it had to do with the File.Open itself, or backups,.... but it all ran into dead ends.

Now what I have found out so far:

- There is no process showing up as accessing the files during the phenomenon.
- The phenomenon can last up to 1 day until suddenly disappearing
  again.
- It only happens for me (other laptops/Desktops using the same program
  never showed that problem so far).
- Last time it happened it was so that I left the program run and after
  1 hour the thread suddenly came to live again and continued as if
  nothing happened (that was the same time the phenomenon stopped
  during that occurance....thus further attempts to access the file
  didn't show any troubles at all thus it is highly probable that the thread did not resume because it just needed to wait a bit longer, but instead that the phenomenon just stopped again.
- Aside from that the phenomenon happens time and again for 1-9 hours (duration varies) and there is no pattern I was able to discern about when it happens or for how long it happens
- Files affected are DIFFERENT files each time. After the phenomenon happened the files show no further problems.

Situation for the files:

- Files are stored on my local network and I copy them to a netdrive.
  The hangup occurs on the access of the locally stored files (thus
  opening them or accessing them). Thus it happens for local files.
- Backups are run for the laptop as a whole BUT during a few of the
  latest occurances NO backup was run.
- During the duration while the phenomenon is active file access to other files than the affeted ones is without problems. Monitoring through resource manager showed no bottleneck (way under 50% disk usage)

As a note on this there can be whole 1-2 weeks between occurances of the phenomenon. without any problems in between.

So my question here is what would be possible causes for this?

Comment: Just speculating.. try to monitor the Disk Read/Writes, may be it bottle necks up..?

Comment: tnx for the comment I updated the question. No no bottleneck seen there during the times the phenomenon happened.

Comment: Sounds to me like something in your own program isn't doing quite what you expect, and locking the files itself in some way. Have you added Diagnostics tracing throughout to make sure the flow is as you expect when these locks occur?

Comment: @JonEgerton That was my original thought back then, but tests showed that whenever I put a lock from inside the program on a file and tried to access it an exceptoin was thrown (which is not the case during the phenomenons). Additionally I have not a single file routine that has a duration in hours. The "problem" is that the thread stops as soon as I try to access / open the file in question and then the stop lasts until the phenomenon ends when the thread suddenly continues as if nothing happened in between.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software running? I regularly encounter strange issues with some of them. If yes, try disable it temporarily and check if it helps.

Comment: @marwie yes, I had checked during the time which files it accesses and the file that was affected was not accessed during that time (additionally if I'm not mistaken the files would have a lock if accessed by the anti virus software? a lock would result in an exception being thrown by the filestream opening)

Comment: @ThomasE. so did you try disabling it? And did the issues persist?

Comment: @Marwie The problem is that currently the issue has subsided since 2 hours again and I'll have to wait until it happens again. Although the virus scanner is running still (and everyday with the same configuration) the problem does not appear every day (nor with the same files).

Comment: thus as the the problem is not showing everyday I dont find it very likely it is the virus scanner (as I dont see any reason why he should  create the problem then only once in a while (almost only once per 1-2 weeks) and then for hours upon hours).